# Restoring a MySQL dump that try to create database in shared host

Tags: database, ssh, mysql, shared-hosting

I have a hosting account at Godaddy. There is automatic MySQL database backup created every day. It is named like `database_name.sql.gz`.

On another shared host of mine, I tried to restore that dump after decomrssing it i.e make it `database_name.sql` using the following command throuh **[putty](/questions/tagged/putty)** and SSH:

```
 mysql -u *****_root -p *****_htest < database_name.sql
```

*Where `*****` is my account's username*

I got the following error:

> ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 22: Access denied for user
>   '*****_root'@'localhost' to database 'database_name'

From the error message it seems that the dump try to create a database named as the original database and it neglect to restore it to the database `*****_htest`.
Is there any way to make this dump file to be restored to the specified database instead of creating new one?

Comment: how did you export it? i mean, there should be an option whether it should create database or tables for you or just dump the whole entry. try to use phpmyadmin, most shared hosting should have that tool.

Comment: @Tezla Using [tag:phpmyadmin] is not an option. The dump file is large i.e over 100 MB.

Comment: strictly speaking, some shared hosting do have a site backup option that let you to upload database backups - however, i wonder if the sql file is actually a mere `insert` and `create` i suspect there are something else. if you could actually look into the 100 MB file content, that'd help to figure it out. on an **unsecure alternative**, try to run it as root or anyone with every kind of access permission (super user).

Comment: @Tezla Thank you very much I have found the solution and make it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have found the solution, by entering the MySQL console and execute the following command:

```
# Enter the console
mysql -u *****_root -p

mysql> use *****_htest
mysql> source database_name.sql
```

That is all!